# Cómo contar líneas de un archivo en C

Tags: c

No logro contar cuántas líneas del archivo tengo. En consola me arroja el número de líneas que me arroja la consola de mi compilador.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    FILE *ptr_file; int c=0,n=0;char l;
    ptr_file = fopen("ListadoCurso.txt","rt");
    if (ptr_file == NULL)
    {
        puts("Error: No se encontró el archivo.");

    }
    while((c = fgetc(ptr_file)) != EOF){
        if( c == '\n')
            n++;
        putchar(c);
    }
    printf ("\nNúmero de líneas del archivo: %d\n",n+1);
    fclose(ptr_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Ya que son muchos datos agrupados en columnas y la ventana de la consola me los indica en 5 lineas, cuando el archivo solo tiene 3...

Esto está en el archivo, como está escrito en el blog de notas, almenos yo lo tengo todo sin salto de linea...

LISTADO (Primera linea)
NOMBRE          P1   P2   P3    P4   P5   P6   P7    P8   P9   P10   T1   T2   T3   T4   T5   1S   2S   1E   2E (Segunda línea)

Danilo Castañeda    8,0  4,5  10,0  7,4  6,0  5,5  10,0  7,5  9,0  10,0  5,0  7,4  8,0  10,0 7,2  5,0  0,0  4,0  5,0 (Tercera línea)

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Dicho eso, ¿qué es "maxilar" en "por no poder maxilar la parte compilada"? ¿Y qué quieres decir con "En consola me arroja el número de líneas que me arroja la propia consola."?

Comment: Estás guardando un caracter en un int (variable `c`). Aunque ese no es el motivo del fallo, ya que un char nl deja de ser un short.

Comment: @RogerMirandaPerez, la función [`fgetc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetc/) devuelve un `int`.

Comment: Lo probe con varios archivos y funciona OK.

Comment: Me pasa igual @CandidMoe , no logro reproducir el problema. Voy a votar el cierre por no poder reproducirse el problema.

Comment: No entiendo el problema. ¿Qué resultado esperas que dé este programa? ¿Qué salida produce?

Comment: Gracias por las aclaraciones...Si lo que sucede es que estoy viendo como contar las lineas de mi archivo, pero me imprime 5 (Yo diría que esta contando las que muestra por pantalla en compilador), pero mi archivo solo tiene 3, eso es lo que no me cuadra.

Comment: Tal vez tenga 5 líneas pero no las ves todas, porque están vacías.

Answer (score 1):

Para contar cuantas líneas tiene un archivo se puede hacer carácter por carácter o linea por linea, en este caso se lee el archivo un carácter a la vez y cuando encontramos que este carácter es igual un salto de linea (\n) incrementamos el contador y continuamos el ciclo, y cuando el carácter es EOF esto significa que el archivo se termino y aquí salimos del ciclo con un break e imprimimos el contador (El numero de líneas del archivo)

```
char ca; 
int cont;

FILE *puntero;
puntero = fopen("input.txt","r");

while(1){

        ca = fgetc(puntero);

        if(ca == '\n'){
            cont++;
        }
        if(ca == EOF){  //Si el caracter es end of file imprimimos el contador y salimos del while
            printf("%d",cont);  //El número de lineas
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: te recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y mires la seccion de como [responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help)